# laravel5 | Homestead | Auth Registration and login is not connect with Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm using laravel5 with Homestead (homestead.app).

At beginning i use localhost, that time laravel Auth working fine.

But move to homestead, its not working(cant connect with DB).

Any configurations need to change ?

MYSQL : Connection

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel5
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: What happens when you [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34126003/4705339)?

Comment: No ji, actually i use .env fil for laravel constant inputs, but homestead set .env file as Production environment. So laravel not get data from that .env file.   Now i sole it. Thank to All...!

Comment: Could you please show a `config/database.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you really have `.env` file uploaded to the host.

The `.env` file is used by `config/database.php` file. 
Ensure that it contains a line

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

and these lines as well:

```
'connections' => [

       //...    

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        //...
],
```